# Combine angular-translate with markdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, markdown, angular-translate, showdown

I use **[angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/)** and **[showdown.js](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown)** in my app (showdown is a port of markdown). I would like to run the output of a translated string through markdown. Do you have any suggestions of how to achieve that?

Let's say I have the string

```
This is a [link](www.google.com).
```

Running it through markdown would give

> This is a [link](http://www.google.com).

My goal is to have strings like this in my translation files, and run the translated text though markdown. I use a **[angular-markdown directive](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive)** which is used like this:

```
<markdown>This is a [link](www.google.com).</markdown>
```

But combining markdown and angular-translate like this

```
<p><markdown>{{ 'MARKDOWNTEST' | translate }}</markdown></p>
```

outputs

```
<p>{{ 'MARKDOWNTEST' | translate }}</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a directive as Alp suggested. In case someone else comes across this problem, here is my solution:

First the **markdown** directive:

```
.directive('markdown', ['$sanitize',function ($sanitize) {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (attrs.markdown) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.markdown, function (newVal) {
                    var html = newVal ? $sanitize(converter.makeHtml(newVal)) : '';
                    element.html(html);
                });
            } else {
                var html = $sanitize(converter.makeHtml(element.text()));
                element.html(html);
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

And the **transdown** directive which translates the key and then uses the markdown directive on the output.

```
.directive('transdown', ['$translate', function ($translate) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            key: '@'
        },
        template: "<span markdown='translation'></span>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.$watch('key', function(n,o){
                if( n !== undefined ){
                    $translate(n).then(function(res){
                        scope.translation = res;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track but I would do it inside a custom interpolator (https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/15_custom-interpolators)

This way the markup would look like: 

<span translate="some_markdown_key" translate-interpolation="markdownFormat"></span>

Answer (score 1):

You could create a translate directive:

```
<translate key="MARKDOWNTEST" />
```

And in the directive you programmatically call the translate function of the i18n service and set the element's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same exact libraries, this works for me :

```
<div btf-markdown="'MARKDOWNTEST' | translate"></div>
```

No need for 2 directives, nor to rewrite the original.

Aside : If you need to use regular html tags inside your strings, you'll have to skip $sanitize.